# SQL Injection blocked by firewall

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have a WordPress site that is guarded by firewall. Today I got a notification of blocked SQL injection. I cannot understand what the hacker is trying to do with the query:

```
https://example.com/?p=121%25%27+UNION+ALL+SELECT+NULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%2CNULL%23
```

My questions are these:

1. What is the purpose of the query and how to find if it did any damage?
2. How to harden my database to stop the attempts?

Based on searching I looked for a table named `sqlmap` which is not present, looked for new users that I didn't create - still nothing.

Comment: fyi `sqlmap` is a penetration testing tool: https://sqlmap.org/

Comment: @PaulG. Didn't know that. But what is the purpose of the query? To null my tables?

Comment: it's penetration testing, so it's just trying to find some sort of vulnerability in there, somewhere. I develop a security plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-simple-firewall/) which has firewall rules designed to detect such things and ultimately block the IP addresses of offenders. If you're worried about these things, try it out and see how you get on.

Comment: @PaulG. Thanks for that. I will look into it.